# How to split text in Google Sheets by searching exact word?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a text `Ahimsa Industries Ltd (NSE:AHIMSA)` in the cell A30.

I need to split/find `NSE:AHIMSA` and Name `Ahimsa Industries Ltd`.

I have created a formula to split text is `=SPLIT(A30, "NSE:")`

I expected result as `Ahimsa Industries Ltd (` and `NSE:AHIMSA)`

After that  I have used formula

```
=LEFT(I30,LEN(I30)-1)
```

to get result as "Ahimsa Industries Ltd" And

```
=LEFT(J30,LEN(J30)-1)
```

to get result as AHIMSA.  But I am not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244), like this:

```cpp
=REGEXEXTRACT(A30,"(.+) \((.+)\)")
```

Another solution using `SPLIT`

```cpp
=SPLIT(SPLIT(A30,")")," (",0)
```